# Is Jesus speaking about the Eucharist in Revelation 3:20?

Tags: revelation, eucharist

> Behold— I stand at the door. And I am knocking. If anyone hears My voice and opens the door, I also will come-in to him. And I will have-dinner (δειπνήσω) with him, and he with Me.
>   (Revelation 3:20) [DLNT]

When one opens the door in response to Jesus knocking, He will come in and have δειπνέω with them and they with Him. [δειπνέω](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1172&t=KJV) is used in only 3 other places; two of which are speaking about the Eucharist (Luke 22:20 and 1 Corinthians 11:24).

Is Jesus saying He will share in the Eucharist to those who respond to Him?

Answer (score 3):

Revelation 3:20 falls within the context of the warnings to the church at Laodicea.  Strictly speaking it is a warning passage that He is coming back at any moment and the church at Laodicea needs to be prepared for His return.  The idea is I am so close that I am standing at the door knocking, are you ready for my return.

In this context then it would not be a reference to the either the Lord's Supper or even to the Passover.  He is using a common metaphor, namely the idea of a friend coming to the home to share a meal.  For those of us who live more on the messy side it would be like the call to the children to hurry up and clean the house, someone is coming soon to have dinner with us.

If there is an allusion here, and the most we could say is it is an allusion, it is the meal that is foretold as part of His second coming--the marriage supper of the lamb.  The marriage of Christ and His bride, the church, will take place in heaven according to Rev. 19:6-9.  A common misconception is that the supper takes place in heaven too.

> > Rev. 19:9 (KJV) 9 And he saith unto me, Write, **Blessed are they which are *called* unto the marriage supper of the Lamb.** And he saith unto me, These are the true sayings of God.

Verse 9 is just the call for the marriage supper, the actual marriage supper will take place on earth as the second coming happens in Rev. 19:11.  In the Olivet Discourse (Matthew 24-25) which deals with the tribulation and the second coming, the marriage supper is described through the parable of the ten virgins in Matthew 25:1-13.  The five virgins who were prepared to enter into the marriage supper and the five virgins who were not allowed to enter into the marriage supper.

**If we are speaking of allusions then this seems the most likely allusion of any but the best we could say is it is an allusion in Revelation 3:20.**

Comment: Do you think the door being opened by the one who hears conflicts with the messianic banquet/marriage supper? The way it reads it sounds like the one inside can prevent the one outside knocking from entering.

Comment: @Revelationlad That is one of the reasons I think that Rev. 3:20 only alludes to the marriage supper and instead is metaphorical as a warning of His return at any moment.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of the question is misleading.  The Greek word, δειπνήσω, only occurs four times (Luke 17:8, 22:20, 1 Cor 11:25, Rev 3:20) with one of these (Luke 17:8) referring to an ordinary meal.  However, the cognate noun, δειπνον, occurs 16 times (Matt 23:6, Mark 6:21, 12:39, Luke 14:12, 16, 17, 24, 20:46, John 12:2, 13:2, 4, 21:20, 1 Cor 11:20, 21, Rev 19:9, 17) with many of them, again, referring to ordinary (non-ritualistic or non-Passover) meals.

However, There is a fascinating reference in one of these.  Luke 14:24 concludes Jesus' parable of the banquet (δειπνον) by saying, "none of those men who were invited shall taste my banquet."  It is might be possible to link this reference (on the basis of Luke 14:14, Rev 19:9, 17) with Rev 3:20; that is, "my banquet" = Jesus' banquet, is that celebratory banquet of the righteous with Jesus.  There is no hint that this is related with a Passover meal unless one takes some theological licence.

Comment: The varied tenses of the verbs supports the idea of a single eating (future-active-indicative), but the eating is with him (singular) not them (plural). Two other points against this referring to the messianic banquet: 1.) I think that meal will proceed whether or not the one hearing the voice opens the door or not. 2.) Presumably the invited guests gain access because the door is opened from them, not the guests opening the door for the host. Also, while the verb/noun argument is valid, Jesus chose the verb not the noun or simply "eat." The connection to the other verb uses seems purposeful.